# Form validation with Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am writing this script just under my HTML code as I want to validate my form with plugin "jQuery.validate.js" but it isn't working at all. I saw it in a video tutorial but it is not working i am working and doing R&D on it from 2 days but all in vain. As I am a nub in javascript and jQuery so please post some helpfull material.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sign_up').validate(function(){
            rules: {
                        first_name: "required",
                        last_name: "required",
                        user_name: "required",
                        father_name: "required",
                        guardian_name: "required",
                        cnic_no: "required",
                        mob_num: "required",
                        ofic_no: "required",
                        res_no: "required",
                        b_day: "required",
                        home_address: "required",
                        office_address: "required",
                        my_country: "required",
                        my_city: "required",
                        radio_gender: "required",
                        radio_status: "required",
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        }


                    },
                    // Specify the validation error messages
                    messages: {
                        first_name: "Please enter your first name",
                        last_name: "Please enter your last name",
                        user_name: "Please enter your user name",
                        father_name: "Please enter your father name",
                        guardian_name: "Please enter your guardian name",
                        cnic_no: "Please enter your cnic",
                        mob_num: "Please enter your mobile number",
                        ofic_no: "Please enter your office number",
                        res_no: "Please enter your residantial no",
                        b_day: "Please enter your birth date",
                        home_address: "Please enter your home address",
                        office_address: "Please enter your office address",
                        my_country: "Please enter your country",
                        my_city: "Please enter your city",
                        radio_gender: "Please select your gender",
                        radio_status: "Please select your status",
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address",

                    }

        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work? Any errors in the console?

Comment: where is your form HTML?

Comment: Actually dear its very lengthy and it may confuse you thats why i damn write it here

Comment: There is no error in console

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML, at the moment we only have half the information to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sign_up').validate(function(){
                              // Specify the validation error messages
                    messages: {
                        first_name: "Please enter your first name",

                    }

        });

    });

$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#sign_up').valid();
}):
```

```html
<form id="sign_up">

    <p>First name: <input id="first_name" required /> <button         id="first_name">Validate</button></p>
   
</form>
```

Comment: Isaac stevens you are doing it using just simple attribute named "required" and i am familiar with it but i want to do it with jquery form validation plugin so your answer isn't helpfull for me its totaly irrelevant